# An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's a constant class I use to invoke some helpers:

```
public static class SecurityHelpers
{
    public static string AntiforgeryTokenSalt = "tokenFooYouTolkienBladeRunner";         
}
```

And here's how I invoke it in one of my forms in my MVC3 web application:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Checkout", FormMethod.Post))
{   
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="@Model.PackageCost"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="$"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="itemdescription" value="@Model.PackageDescriptor"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="digital"/>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken(App.WebUI.Helpers.SecurityHelpers.AntiforgeryTokenSalt)

    <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn primary frmsubmit" />
}
```

And in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = SecurityHelpers.AntiforgeryTokenSalt)]
public ActionResult Index(decimal amount, string currency, string itemDescription, string type)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
}
```

The error is fired in my Controller, it says:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Any ideas why this isn't working? The `Salt` attribute of the ValidateAntiForgeryToken decorator is a string and my constant is also a string, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A static string is not a constant.

Try changing

```
public static string AntiforgeryTokenSalt = "tokenFooYouTolkienBladeRunner";
```

to

```
public const string AntiforgeryTokenSalt = "tokenFooYouTolkienBladeRunner";
```